# Notepad++ User Defined Language hex numbers

Tags: notepad++

I have a user defined language for Notepad++. There is an issue with numbers. I have numbers set to highlight as 0xFF0000 (bright red). This works great for numbers like 5, 844, 108293. The problem lies with hex numbers like 0x50, 0x83, etc. In the case of the hex numbers, the 0 shows correctly highlighted, then the x50 will show up as default color.

I know this can be set correctly to highlight the entire 0x50 as if I switch to C++, the numbers are highlighted properly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Notepad++ 6.2.2 you can define style for hexadecimal numbers as shown below in the UDF dialog:

[image]

However, one caveat I've found which is true for a lot of the options in the UDF lexer is that except numbers at the end of a line, a space following the number is required for the lexer to determine it's a number.

So for example, the 0xFF and 0x00 will be treated as numbers, while 0x9F will not:

```
white = 0xFF
black = 0x00
SetColor(i, x, r.Min.Y, 0x9F)
```

Comment: Notepad++ 6.4.5 allows to fully define hex representation, a bit tricky though. Set Prefix 2: "0x" and Extras 1: "A B C D E F a b c d e f". (Do not exchange Prefix 2 with 1 nor Extras 1 with 2, otherwise it does not work)

Comment: Here we are a decade later and it still doesn't support regular expressions matching on items, or at least wildcards of some sort, either there is some other plugin that does that, or, they just don't want to make npp any more flexible than it is. go figure...